# Should I declare and create an instance of a class inside loop?

Tags: c#, class, object, oop

I wrote a simple console game (TicTacToe to be specific) for practice. After game over I need to reset the game so I am creating a new instance of the game class.

Is the old instance of class destroyed before creating the new one?

If not then it is getting stacked up in the memory which is not good. So what is the better practice here?

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool restart = true;  //stores decision whether to restart the game
            do
            {
                Game game = new Game();  //a simple console game
                game.start();            //start -> play -> game over
                restart = playAgain();   //playAgain returns a boolean
            } while (restart);
        }
```

The code is written in c# if that is relevant.

Comment: You are indeed creating a new instance of `Game` with each iteration of the loop, and the old instance from the previous iteration falls out of scope and is garbage-collected.  The internal specifics of that garbage collection will depend on what language you're using, which is something you'll need to decide.  (This looks like C#, but you include Java in the tags...)  But those specifics *shouldn't* really be relevant.  Whether or not this is the *correct* approach is up to your design, how your `Game` object works, whether it can be re-used, etc.

Comment: Whether you "should" do that depends on the nature of "Game", which we have no knowledge of.  If a Game can be played only once, then you obviously have to make a new Game to be able to "play again".  I see nothing wrong with doing that.  You might start to have a problem after a few million games in quick succession :-)

Comment: @David Will it make any difference if I used recursion instead of do-while?

Comment: Yes, because the old 'game' will not go out of scope before the new 'game' is created, unless you carefully arrange that 'game' is not accessible at the recursive call.

Comment: @avm: Maybe.  In general, there is a difference between doing one thing vs. doing another thing.  What that difference is and how it affects the system depends on what that other code is and what it does.  What exactly are you trying to ask?  Do you have specific code which is doing something unexpected in a specific way?

Comment: @passer-by Yes I need to 'recreate' the game from start if thats what you're asking. So does this mean the instances are not getting destroyed?

Comment: @avm: In the code shown, each instance of `Game` is falling out of scope and being garbage-collected with each iteration of the loop.  Whether or not there exists a brief moment where two instances exist simultaneously in memory, we can't say.  That's a matter for the garbage collection and *shouldn't* be a problem, such micro-optimizations are not necessary.  Whether or not `Game` internally has a memory leak unrelated to the code shown, we can't say.  If you're just asking whether or not the heap is cleaned up when a reference is no longer in scope, the answer is yes.

Comment: Instances get destroyed when the garbage collector runs, which is in general unpredictable and not the concern of the application code.  The garbage collector is a mechanism for giving the appearance of infinite memory.   It should not matter to you if unreachable Games are hanging around for an indefinite time, except in some performance-sensitive cases (which this is not).

Comment: I have updated the post with full code.

Comment: @David - it becomes **collectable** but it is not necessarily immediately **collected**.

Comment: @David I am asking whether the reference goes out of scope after one iteration of loop is completed. So if we ignore any mishaps during runtime then program should never cause OutOfMemory in ideal conditions due to the loop?

Comment: At this level, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @CaiusJard I know that. This was just a reference. At a level where it does matter would you use a loop? What are the alternative approaches in general?

Comment: You don't need to post all of your code to ask this question. The only part that really matters is the `Main` method with the `do` loop and the variable.

Comment: @ScottHannen The original question was posted with that much code only but some comments were asking for implementation or atleast I thought so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version:

> Should I declare and create an instance of a class inside loop?

Yes, if you only need that instance inside the loop.

---

When we create an object

```cs
Game game = new Game();
```

...it "exists" in memory as long as there are references to it. When there are no longer any references to an object it becomes available for garbage collection.

So the question is, what references are there to the created `Game` object? It appears that there is only one reference, the `game` variable that you assign it to.

So now the question is, how long does that variable live? It lives as long as the scope within which it is defined. In this case you're defining it within a `do` loop. As soon as that execution of the loop is over (a few lines later) the variable goes out of scope. In other words, the scope within which it was defined no longer exists. In simpler terms, that variable no longer exists.

The variable is the only reference to that exact `Game` object. When the variable goes out of scope, there are no longer any references to that `Game` object. It will be garbage collected. (That doesn't happen instantly, but we don't have to worry about exactly when it happens. We don't usually care. That's something the framework worries about for us.)

What if the loop repeats? Think of the inside of that loop as a method that gets called over and over. When it gets called again, the `game` variable is new, because it's declared inside the loop. It doesn't "know" anything about the previous execution of the loop or the previous `Game` object. That variable went out of scope at the end of that iteration of the loop.

How do we tell what the scope of a variable is? One easy way is to see where we're allowed to use it.

If you tried to write this, using the `game` variable outside of the loop:

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool restart = true;  //stores decision whether to restart the game
            do
            {
                Game game = new Game();  //a simple console game
                game.start();            //start -> play -> game over
                restart = playAgain();   //playAgain returns a boolean
            } while (restart);

        }
        game.Start(); // <-- Outside the loop where it was declared
```

...it wouldn't compile. That's because the variable is declared inside the loop, so it's not available outside the loop. Just like if we declare a local variable inside one method it's not visible or accessible inside another method.

Comment: Cleared all my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (because I'm relatively new to this) all variables that you declare in the do scope are local, and when the program is out of that scope those variables are destroyed. So, the instance of the game class that you declare in the do scope is local and will therefore be destroyed when the while loop checks the condition again.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new instance of the Game class called `game` all you are doing is setting the variable `game` to a new instance. `game` is saved in memory so the next time you start a game it will take the variable `game` and regardless of what state it's in, will set it to a new instance. This means that there is never more than once instance of that class regardless of it being in a do/while loop because you are using the same variable.